# Problems with Stripe Class Require nor Include are working

Tags: php, include, require

This is driving me nutso.... I am trying the Stripe API for payments and I am following the API documentation.  Including and require I have always found to be pretty straight forward but for some reason it still cannot find the Class Stripe when it is clearly there...

```
Directory Structure

Stripe\Stripe.php
test.php


test.php:

require 'Stripe\Stripe.php';
$stripe = array(
  "secret_key"      => "sk_test_mkGsLxxxxxx87HYfJVLf",
  "publishable_key" => "pk_test_czwzxxxxxxxxOEOqbMTRzG"
);

Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

`Fatal error: Class 'Stripe' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\thefloat\test.php` on line 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out answer from Josh Storz on this page...

[Issue with stripe payment set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922589/issue-with-stripe-payment-set-up/29374899#29374899)

Solved the problem for me.